# DisplayAlert causing crash of Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a display alert for a simple yes or no dialogue but it's freezing my UI and I have no idea why.

```
private  async void BtnDeleteStockTake_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        var selectedItem = gridItems.SelectedItem as StockTakeTransArgsSage;
        var action =  await DisplayAlert("First 1", "Are you sure you wish to delete Stock Take", "Yes", "No");
        if (action)
        {
            StockTakeTransArgsSage _item = new StockTakeTransArgsSage();
           _item =database.GetSingleStockTake(selectedItem.StockTakeId).Result;
           _item.Quantity = decimal.Parse(txtQty.Text);

            int updated = await database.DeleteStockTake(_item);
            await DisplayAlert("Second 1", "Stock Take Deleted", "OK");          
            await RebindData();
        }
}
```

The weird thing, as well as the display alert from the first one, do not dismiss

It's causing the UI to crash out with a fatal error however if I step through my code normally without the display alert it's fine it does display the alert but then freezes.

My Delete stock function

```
public async Task<int> DeleteStockTake(StockTakeTransArgsSage args)
{
   return await database.DeleteAsync(args);


}
```

My Get Single function.

```
public async Task<StockTakeTransArgsSage> GetSingleStockTake(int ID)
{
        StockTakeTransArgsSage _stocktake = new StockTakeTransArgsSage();          
        _stocktake = await database.Table<StockTakeTransArgsSage>().Where(w => w.StockTakeId == ID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();       
        return _stocktake;

}
```

Comment: why are u anwering on something that has an accpeted answer

Comment: I was just revisiting it, I have a feeling that if you do this it might work: var action =  await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First 1", "Are you sure you wish to delete Stock Take", "Yes", "No");

Comment: It was a know bug at the time in xamrain forms that has noq been fixed i got it working with the solution below

Comment: Thats odd am having the exact same issue in march 2022 now

Comment: Haha  that’s the best part when you see your own stackoverflow question/answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely from the behavior you are describing (and looking at your code), it sounds like it's because the Display Alert is not being run on the UI thread, and this causes the app to wait for you to dismiss this alert box before being able to do anything. So your app is not crashing or freezing, it's just launching the alert on a different thread.
So change it to the following:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
            DisplayAlert("Second 1", "Stock Take Deleted", "OK");          
});
```

Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your code only those lines can cause that behavior:

```
       StockTakeTransArgsSage _item = new StockTakeTransArgsSage();
       _item =database.GetSingleStockTake(selectedItem.StockTakeId).Result;
       _item.Quantity = decimal.Parse(txtQty.Text);

        int updated = await database.DeleteStockTake(_item);
```

Those lines cannot be executed on UI thread without freezing it for some time. That may cause the crash, you haven't provided any information of what you see in output for the crash so it is the only likely explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried awaiting like below

```
StockTakeTransArgsSage _item = new StockTakeTransArgsSage();
           _item = await database.GetSingleStockTake(selectedItem.StockTakeId);
           _item.Quantity = decimal.Parse(txtQty.Text);
```

As I can see this will work. And also make sure that until finish the process you are not touching any other UI component in the screen.